# Error at constructor : Expected an identifier?

Tags: c++, oop

I am working with a bunch of classes with composition and I keep getting this error (Expected an identifier) when I try to implement the constructor , here the class header:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H_
#define STUDENT_H_

#include "University.h"
class Student {
public:
    Student(); // constructor
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, Student &); // print the student data
    friend istream & operator>>(istream &, Student &); // to read student data
private:
    const int id; 
    string name; 
    int marks[5];
    Date admissionDate; // Composition
    University university;  // Composition
};

#endif
```

what do I need to do to solve this error ?

here's the cpp but I still did not implement the other io functions because I want to solve that error first..

```
#include "Student.h"
Student::Student(){}
ostream & operator<<(ostream &, Student &){} 
istream & operator>>(istream &, Student &){}
```

Comment: I think you should show your try to implement the constructor.

Comment: Does every student need a copy of the university object? Won't a reference suffice? I assume `University` holds students, which may be the cause additional errors.

Comment: What's a `University`?

Comment: You should include the exact error message and the exact offending lines of code in your question.

Comment: @StoryTeller It's an institution of higher learning ;)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, Troll joke is trolling :P

Comment: no it does not , University only has two io functions and an object from class date

Comment: @CaptainObvlious it's right under the curly braces of the constructor body ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `Student` has a `const int id` member, you need to initialize it in the constructor's
initialization list. E.g.:

```
Student::Student() : id(0)
{ }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor should be defined the following way

```
Student::Student() { /* some code */ }
```

Comment: @Matteo Italia, Grazia, Lei e molto cortese.:)

Comment: But the constructor provided in the header is empty , I think it has something to do with initializer list thingy, but what do I need to to initialize ?

Comment: @user3125670, At least you must initialize const int id; in the mem-initializer because it is a constant. I think you must declare constructor with at least one parameter that will set id. Or remove qualifier const from the definition of data member id.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank you very much, that was the cause of it.. how did I forget such thing , Thanks again and thanks everyone :D